# sudo apt-get update - 'Skipping acuire of config file 'partner/binary-*****/packages'' (18.10)

Tags: apt, updates

Can anyone help me fix this update error?

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com cosmic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com cosmic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com cosmic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com cosmic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com cosmic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
*
*
*
W: Conflicting distribution: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease (expected cosmic-security but got cosmic)
```

Comment: Go to Software & Updates, tab "Other software", and uncheck the Partner repositories that, apparently, no longer exist.

Comment: By the way, it's just a warning. Things should proceed as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the repositories (partner) worked.

Go to Software & Updates, tab "Other software", and uncheck the Partner repositories that, apparently, no longer exist -Jos